# what kind of action should I take to get latest source code in "master" branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio

i am green to use git in visual studio (2015).

We have two branches in total: "master" and "brnch-1".
i am at branch "brnch-1".

what kind of action should I take to get latest code in "master" branch?

I know "Get Latest" in TFS. but now i dont see a "get latest" in right click menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to checkout to master first.

`git checkout master`

Then Pull and merge/rebase

`git pull --rebase` // I am rebasing here

If you want the changes to come in your `brnch-1` brnach also.

After pulling for master checkout to that branch.

`git chekout brnch-1`

And rebase/merge

`git rebase master` // Rebasing here. You can choose to merge if you want